# Timeout issue facing on creating new shortcode Erlang

Tags: server, timeout, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I was trying to implement an emoji server and write codes for it. But when I test it in the terminal it is showing timeout error. For checking the code please check the `alias` function for it:

```
-spec alias(Pid :: pid(), Short1 :: shortcode(), Short2 :: shortcode()) -> ok | {error, Reason :: term()}.
alias(Pid, Short1, Short2) when is_pid(Pid), is_list(Short1), is_list(Short2) ->
    Pid ! {alias, Short1, Short2},
    receive
        {ok, Short2} -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    after 1000 -> {error, timeout}
    end.

emoji_loop(State = #emoji_state{}) ->
    receive
        {alias, Short1, Short2} ->
            io:format("Received alias: Short1 = ~p, Short2 = ~p~n", [Short1, Short2]),
            case dict:find(Short1, State#emoji_state.shortcodes) of
                {ok, _} ->
                    case dict:find(Short2, State#emoji_state.aliases) of
                        {ok, _} -> emoji_loop(State);
                        error ->
                            NewAliases = dict:store(Short2, Short1, State#emoji_state.aliases),
                            emoji_loop(State#emoji_state{aliases = NewAliases})
                    end;
                error -> emoji_loop(State)
            end;
    end.
```

I have added `io:format` to debug the code and it seems my new_shortcode function has the issue, but I could not able to find out the issue.

Here is the input that I entered into the terminal:

```
{ok, Pid} = emoji:start([{"happy", <<"">>}, {"sad", <<"">>}]).
```

and then received the output like this:

```
{ok,<0.92.0>}
```

Then again entered another input

```
emoji:new_shortcode(Pid, "dollar", <<""/utf8>>).
```

and received a message like this:

```
Received new_shortcode: Short = "dollar", Emo = <<240,159,146,181>>
```

with timeout error `{error,timeout}`.

How can I run the create shortcode function perfectly?

Thank you for the clarification again but still I am struggling with the stop function. Here is my code for stop function in the loop.

```
{stop, Pid} -> 
        if
            Pid =:= self() ->
                exit(Pid);
            true ->
                emoji_loop(State)
        end
```

In this stop function I need to stop the server when write the command emoji:stop(Pid). After that the server's commands for emoji will not work and give errors.
Here is the stop main function where pass the Pid as you instructed.

```
-spec stop(Pid :: pid()) -> ok | {error, Reason :: term()}.
stop(Pid) when is_pid(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {stop, self()},
    receive
        ok -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    after 5000 ->
        {error, timeout}
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `new_shortcode/3` function, we see that it sends a message to `Pid` and then expects a response, but it fails with `{error, timeout}` because it never gets that response:

```
new_shortcode(Pid, Short, Emo) when is_pid(Pid), is_binary(Emo), is_list(Short) ->
    Pid ! {new_shortcode, Short, Emo},
    receive
        {ok, Short} -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    after 1000 -> {error, timeout}
    end.
```

The `Pid` here is the process running the `emoji_loop/1` function, which receives commands in the form of tuples and carries them out by changing the loop state. But what the `emoji_loop/1` function doesn't do is send a message back to the process sending the command, which is why a function like `new_shortcode/3` times out waiting for a reply.

To fix it, send the caller's pid to `emoji_loop/1` so it can reply. This means changing `new_shortcode/1` to add `self()` into the command tuple it sends to `emoji_loop/1`:

```
new_shortcode(Pid, Short, Emo) when is_pid(Pid), is_binary(Emo), is_list(Short) ->
    Pid ! {new_shortcode, Short, Emo, self()},
    receive
        {ok, Short} -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    after 1000 -> {error, timeout}
    end.
```

We then have to change `emoji_loop/1` to send a reply back to the caller. For example, change the handling of `new_shortcode` like this:

```
        {new_shortcode, Short, Emo, Pid} ->
            io:format("Received new_shortcode: Short = ~p, Emo = ~p~n", [Short, Emo]),
            NewShortCodes = case dict:find(Short, State#emoji_state.shortcodes) of
                {ok, _} -> State#emoji_state.shortcodes;
                error ->
                    dict:store(Short, Emo, State#emoji_state.shortcodes)
            end,
            Pid ! {ok, Short},
            emoji_loop(State#emoji_state{shortcodes = NewShortCodes});
```

With this change and a similar change for `lookup`, we can see it works as expected:

```
3> {ok, Pid} = emoji:start([{"happy", <<"">>}, {"sad", <<"">>}]).
{ok,<0.138.0>}
4> emoji:new_shortcode(Pid, "dollar", <<""/utf8>>).
Received new_shortcode: Short = "dollar", Emo = <<240,159,146,181>>
ok
5> emoji:lookup(Pid, "dollar").
Received lookup: Short = "dollar"
{ok,<<240,159,146,181>>}
```

We have to make similar changes to all command functions that expect replies from the `emoji_loop/1` process.

I strongly suggest you to look into using a [`gen_server`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) rather than rolling your own server, as it easily handles everything you're trying to do here and also helps with error handling and with process management and cleanup.

*Update: the question was revised to add a specific question about `emoji:stop/1`, so I'm updating my answer to address it:*

The original `stop` handler in `emoji_loop/1` simply exited:

```
    stop ->
        exit(normal)
```

To address the timeout problem, you've modified it to be:

```
    {stop, Pid} -> 
        if
            Pid =:= self() ->
                exit(Pid);
            true ->
                emoji_loop(State)
        end
```

But there are two problems with this change:

1. `Pid` will never be `self()` because `emoji_loop/1` doesn't send itself messages, so the first clause of the `if` just never happens.
2. Having `emoji_loop/1` call itself recursively as in the `true` clause means that the loop process keeps running rather than stopping as requested.

To fix these issues, you have to fix the `stop` handler just the same as the `new_shortcode` handler was fixed above: pass the caller's pid with the command, and have the command handler send a reply back to the caller. If we go back to the original `stop` handler and make these changes, we get:

```
    {stop, Pid} ->
        Pid ! ok,
        exit(normal)
```

And the `stop/1` function has to be changed to send its pid with the command:

```
stop(Pid) when is_pid(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {stop, self()},
    receive
        ok -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    after 1000 -> {error, timeout}
    end.
```

We can test `stop/1` to verify that it actually stops the loop process:

```
2> {ok, Pid} = emoji:start([{"happy", <<"">>}, {"sad", <<"">>}]).
{ok,<0.117.0>}
3> is_process_alive(Pid).
true
4> emoji:stop(Pid).
ok.
5> is_process_alive(Pid).
false
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have successfully run the new_shortcode and lookup functions and there is no timeout issue now. But unfortunately I was unable to fix the rest of the functions, could you please help me to understand the rest of the functions.

Comment: Each function sends a command tuple to the loop process, and most functions then call `receive` expecting a message back from the loop process. For each function expecting a reply, you have to send `self()` in the command tuple, and you have to modify each command handler in the `emoji_loop/1` function to send back a reply that matches one of the cases the calling function's `receive` expects. If this is still not clear, you'll have to explain in more detail what you don't understand.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check my stop function, I need stop/1, and passing by the process id the server should stop but I am getting timeout error. :( . Really trying to fix this issue. I will defiantly try to learn 'gen_server' , but as I am very very new in the erLang language, so want to clear my concept about server. Thanks again for your all help.

Comment: My updated answer addresses your `stop/1` question. (BTW the language is named "Erlang", not "erLang".)

Comment: You are a great mentor :) . The stop function is working perfectly. I just started my journey with ErLang and trying to fix easy things. Thanks a lot again.